# Combining different classifiers yields lower accuracy than a Random Forest alone

Tags: machine-learning, logistic, classification, random-forest, ensemble-learning

I used the following classifiers (with accuracies):

1. Random Forest - 85 %
2. SVM - 78 %
3. Adaboost - 82%
4. Logistic regression - 80%

When I used voting from the above classifiers for final classification, I got lower accuracy than when I used Random Forest alone.

How is this possible? All classifiers are giving more or less the same accuracy when used individually, then how does Random Forest outperform their combined result?

Answer (score 1):

I also frequently find that Random Forests outperform other classifiers, and that they can even outperform combinations of other classifiers. Random Forests are simply *good*.

It's hard to answer what specifically is the issue in your particular instance. One thing that could have an impact could be correlated regressors. SVM and logistic regression have a hard time with correlated predictors, as can [AdaBoost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AdaBoost), depending on which underlying weak learner is used. Random Forests, through ["feature bagging"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_forest#From_bagging_to_random_forests) (selecting a small subset of predictors in building each separate tree) mitigates the effect of correlated regressors.

If this really is the underlying issue, you could look at dimension reduction techniques like PCA before feeding the transformed data to your SVM and logistic regression.